# conformal maps from upper half disk to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Find all conformal maps from the upper half of the unit disk onto the unit disk.

I know how to construct a conformal map onto the unit disk, but I do not know how to find all such maps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you know one, you get all by composing with disc automorphisms which are well known; note that if $f:A \to B, g:A \to B$ conformal bijections, $h=g\circ f^{-1}:B \to B$ is a conformal automorphism of $B$ and $g=h\circ f$ and viceversa

Comment: Yes, thank you for this

Comment: Happy to be of help